# How do I insert a character into a string at any given point? (Processing)

Tags: string, insert, character, processing, stringbuffer

I am trying to insert a character into a string using Processing.
 After some reading around I tried out the following (I think Java) code:

```
1: String st = new String("abcde");
2: st = StringBuffer(st).insert(2, "C");
```

and got the following response:

```
the function StringBuffer(String) does not exist
```

Is there a different/simpler way of doing this? Do I need to use StringBuffer? I'm a fairly novice programmer so any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: are we talking about http://processing.org?

Comment: If you want to use non-Processing Java classes in the Processing IDE, you need to import them.  You don't need StringBuffer for this, but if you wanted to use it, you would add `import java.lang.StringBuffer` to the top of your code.  @fguchelaar's suggestion to use String.substring() is the way I'd go with this.  Note that because String is part of java.lang, you don't need to import it to use it.  Here is the full documentation for String, dig around to see if there's anything else of use to you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I've been looking at the [processing 'Extended Language API'](http://processing.org/reference/) and there doesn't seem to be some function like that out of the box.

If you look at the [String](http://processing.org/reference/String.html) class's [substring()](http://processing.org/reference/String_substring_.html) function, you'll see an example where there is a String that is cut into two pieces at position 2. And then printed out with other characters between them. Will that help you any further?

```
String str1 = "CCCP"; 
String str2 = "Rabbit"; 
String ss1 = str1.substring(2);     // Returns "CP"
String ss2 = str2.substring(3);     // Returns "bit"
String ss3 = str1.substring(0, 2);  // Returns "CC"
println(ss1 + ":" + ss2 + ":" + ss3);  // Prints 'CP:bit:CC'
```

If we take your example, this would insert the 'C' at the right position:

```
String st = new String("abcde");
String p1 = st.substring(0,2); // "ab"
String p2 = st.substring(2); // "cde"
st = p1 + "C" + p2; // which will result in "abCcde"
```

Or create a function for it. Mind you, not super-robust (no checks for empty strings, overflow etc), but does the job:

```
String insert(original, toInsert, position){
  String p1 = original.substring(0,position);
  String p2 = original.substring(position);
  return p1 + toInsert + p2;
}

...

String st = new String("abcde");
st = insert(st, "C", 2); // "abCcde"
st = insert(st, "D", 4); // "abCcDde"
```

*tested at http://sketch.processing.org*

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for taking the time to look at this problem for me. I'll need to have a play with this and see how I get on. At first glance it looks to achieve the same outcome, however I need to insert multiple items in each string - would it still be possible with this method?

Comment: You could create a function for it. I'll update the answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert multiple items with this functions by calling it once for each insert.  To make it easier, insert them from right to left as otherwise the position to insert will change as you so inserts to the left.

Example:

```
String original="The quick fox jumped over lazy dog";
// lets insert "brown" at position 10, "the" at 21, and "'s back" at 34 to make
// "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back"
println( original );
original= insertInString( original, "'s back", 34 );
original= insertInString( original, "the ", 26 );
original= insertInString( original, "brown ", 10 );
println( original );
```

This generated the following output:

```
The quick fox jumped over lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back
```

If you insert from left to right, the positions have to be adjusted after each insert.